# How to skip current cell in a for each loop

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I have the following code which sends out emails for every cell that contains an email address in column K.

This would work except for the header in the table isn't an email address, so it breaks the code. I tried to skip the header by specifying "if cell.value = CONTACT METHOD, which is the header name text, then go to Next cell"

but this causes a "Next without for" error.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("K").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    If cell.Value Like "*@*" Then
    finaladdress = cell.Value

    Else
    finaladdress = cell.Value & "@email.smsglobal.com"

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = finaladdress
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to skip cell **K1** in looping down column **K** then:

```
For Each cell In Columns("K2:K" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the code within the `FOR/EACH` loop within a separate `IF` statement, as below:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("K").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value = "CONTACT METHOD" Then
        'Do Nothing, or Enter code here
    Else
        If cell.Value Like "*@*" Then
        finaladdress = cell.Value

        Else
        finaladdress = cell.Value & "@email.smsglobal.com"

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = finaladdress
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                        "your account up to date"
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```